# How I can POST (http client) data from input and result data display to component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, angular-httpclient

I have problem with display data in component who I POST from input to server. In input I need enter companyId and after POST request server return specific data from company. In console I get response from server with data but I don't know how to display data by *ngFor loop in component.

Do you know how resolve this? Thank you for your help.

I expecting for display this data in component:

Name: IT company

City: Los Angeles

District: California

Id: 36786891 <- this is companyId

**My code:**

**Response from server in console:**

```
{
  city: "Los Angeles"
  district: "California"
  id: "36745687"
  name: "IT company"
}
```

**model:**

```
export class Fin {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  city: string;
  district: string;
}
```

**service:**

```
searchByCompanyId(companyId){
    return this.http.post(environment.appApiUrl + '/api/url', companyId, {responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

**component.ts:**

```
  finForm: FormGroup;
  finData: Fin[] = [];
  companyId: any;

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.finForm = new FormGroup({
      companyId: new FormControl()
    });
  }

  submit() {
    this.apiService.searchByCompanyId(this.finForm.value).subscribe( response => {
      this.companyId = response;
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" [formGroup]="finForm" (submit)="submit()" class="form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>ID</mat-label>
    <input matInput id="companyId" type="number" formControlName="companyId">
  </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-raised-button class="form-button" color="primary" type="submit">search</button>
</form>

<div *ngFor="let item of finData">
  <p>Meno: {{item.name}}</p>
  
  <p>ID: {{item.id}}</p>

  <p>District: {{item.district}}</p>
  
  <p>City: {{item.city}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: `finData` data is empty as you are inserting response in `companyId`. Insert your response data in `finData`. Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: I don't see where you're setting finData...looks like you're logging it to the console, but not setting it in the subscribe call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. The variable name the template uses is called `finData`, but in your response you are populating `companyId` with the results.
2. `*ngFor` needs an array of data, but your api response is a single item.

You can easily address these with one simple change:

```
 this.apiService.searchByCompanyId(this.finForm.value).subscribe(response => {
   this.finData = [response];  // <-----
   console.log(response);
 });
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66547634?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

change

this.companyId = response

to

this.finData = response

Comment: Yes I tried this but i have erorr ->  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fin[]'

Comment: did you try `finData.push(response)` ?

Comment: what are you expecting in the response? is it stringified?

Comment: @GauravGupta yes I tried but still error -> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Fin'

Comment: @tcrite I need data from object who I get from server

Comment: @FrontierMatty change your class to interface in model.ts

Comment: @FrontierMatty judging by the error you're getting, it seems as though it's stringified...can you try a JSON.parse

Comment: so this.finData = JSON.parse(response)

Comment: @tcrite still data display only in console and show this ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'IT company.'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: @FrontierMatty are you sure you're getting an array of data...looks like you're getting an object, but expecting an array? I'd say inspect your console log to ensure it's the data you're expecting.

Comment: @tcrite and what I try next? because I get object data from server not array.

Comment: can you post the data you're getting back? if not, inspect the data to see if maybe the array is a property of the object.

Comment: also, maybe you shouldn't be using an ngFor?

Comment: Ok, it's work. Thanks for your instructions. I deleted `ngFor, finData: Fin[] = [];` this replaced by `finData: Fin`; without arrays and create variable `dataIsReady = false` and in method submit() I add `this.finData = JSON.parse(response);` `this.dataIsReady = true;`. In HTML component I add  `<div *ngIf="dataIsReady"> name: {{finData.name}}</div>` and display data from server.

Comment: glad I could help